# Build a staircase for my kid

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The other day, my son asked me to build him a staircase using Lego-ish blocks. And I came up with something like this:

[image: Staircase]

Then my kid asked me for a program using the least number of bytes that generated a similar staircase in a computer screen. I am not that good at [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so I need your help. I need a program that:

- Receives a positive integer with the number of levels the staircase needs to have.
- Outputs a drawing of a staircase, with the pattern you see in the image.

The output will be in text format but the bricks can be distinguished one from another. For instance, you may use the '█' character as half a block and paint it in any color you want, or just choose any character of your choice.

Restrictions:

- Blocks need to be of three different colors, which will be used as long as possible (if input is 1 or 2 there are not enough blocks to use all three colors). If you want, you may use the '░▒▓' characters, for instance, or just select three different characters.
- No two blocks of the same color or pattern can be side to side in a single row.

My son does not really care about trailing spaces or new lines as long as a staircase is drawn.

Examples (sorry for the bad choice of characters):

```
Input: 1
Output:
██

Input: 2
Output:
██
 ▓▓

Input: 3
Output:
██
 ▓▓
██░░

Input: 5
Output:
██
 ██
██░░
 ██░░
██░░▓▓
```

Comment: Tell your child that the fun is in building / programming it himself :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo He is only three, he does not even know what programming is. :-)

Comment: By the way, this is my first question here, so any advice, corrections and/or improvements will be welcome!

Comment: Welcome to the site! Combining ASCII art and graphical output is usually frowned upon, as it results in sort of two parallel challenges. Also, if you go for ASCII, I would allow actual ASCII characters to be used (I think you already do, but perhaps be more explicit), as some languages may have difficulty with non ASCII characters

Comment: @LuisMendo thank you for the advice! I have restricted the game to just ASCII art.

Comment: FYI the blocks are called Duplo

Comment: I'm not clear on what it means for blocks to use three different colors as long as possible.

Comment: @dzaima no, the order does not matter as long as two bricks of the same color are not side to side.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Does that mean we can only use two colors as long they alternate on each line?

Comment: @xnor no, you need to use three different "colors" in any way you want.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing duplo doesn't have round buttons.

Comment: Do I need to handle case `0` or can I assume it will be at least `1`?

Comment: @Christoph no, you can assume the integer will always be positive.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing The blocks in the Question aren't Duplo, Duplo is [Lego compatible](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/53/Old_duplo_bricks.jpg), those are [Lego Baby](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lego_Baby). They *were* originally called Duplo Primo and I wish they had a different name than *either* of those two, but they are technically a different product than both Lego and Duplo.

Comment: You may have to change the accepted answer, following Jonathan Allan's recent edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>21 19</s>  16 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
d2SR+%3x2⁶;ṙḂµ€Y
```

A full program printing the result.

Uses `00`, `11`, and `22` as the blocks.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//ZDJTUislM3gy4oG2O@G5meG4gsK14oKsWf///zc)**

#### How?

```
d2SR+%3x2⁶;ṙḂµ€Y - Main link: number n
             µ€  - for €ach "row" in n (i.e. for row, r = 1 to n inclusive):
d2               -   divmod 2   -> [integer-divide by 2, remainder] i.e. [r/2, r%2]
  S              -   sum        -> r/2 + r%2
   R             -   range      -> [1, 2, 3, ..., r/2 + r%2]
    +            -   add r      -> [r+1, r+2, r+3, ..., r + r/2 + r%2]
     %3          -   modulo 3   -> [r%3+1, r%3+2, r%3+0, ..., (r + r/2 + r%2)%3]
                 -   e.g.: r: 1  , 2  , 3    , 4    , 5      , 6      , 7       , ...
                             [2], [0], [1,2], [2,0], [0,1,2], [1,2,0], [2,0,1,2], ...
       x2        -   times 2 - repeat each twice (e.g. [2,0,1,2] -> [2,2,0,0,1,1,2,2]
         ⁶       -   literal space character
          ;      -   concatenate (add a space character to the left)
            Ḃ    -   r mod 2 (1 if the row is odd, 0 if it is even (1 at the top))
           ṙ     -   rotate (the list) left by (r mod 2)
               Y - join with newlines
                 - implicit print (no brackets printed due to the presence of characters)
```

Answer (score 11):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 55 bytes

```python
i=2
exec"print(i%2*' '+`2%i*1122`*i)[:i];i+=1;"*input()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9PWiCu1IjVZqaAoM69EI1PVSEtdQV07wUg1U8vQ0MgoQStTM9oqM9Y6U9vW0FpJKzOvoLREQ/P/f0MDAA)

Cycles between blocks of `22, 44`, except the top row is `00`. For example, on input 10, prints

```python
00
 22
2244
 2244
224422
 224422
22442244
 22442244
2244224422
 2244224422
```

Prints rows of increasing length `i=2,3,..` by creating a space for odd lengths, repeating the pattern `i` times, and trunctating to length `i`. The pattern is `2244` for all rows except the first one `i=2` for which it's `0`. This is achieved with the arithmetic expression `2%i*1122`.

Comment: Uses only two colors for case 3.

Comment: Very clever fix!

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), 80 bytes

```
n=>eval(`for(s=11,i=1;i++<n;)s+='\\n'+(' '+'2233'.repeat(n)).substr(i%2,i+1);s`)
```

```js
f=
n=>eval(`for(s=11,i=1;i++<n;)s+='\\n'+(' '+'2233'.repeat(n)).substr(i%2,i+1);s`)
console.log(f(+prompt()))
```

---

## JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

Previous solution.

```
n=>[11,...Array(n).fill(' '+'2233'.repeat(n)).map((r,n)=>r.slice(n%2,n+3+n%2))].join`
`
```

Answer (score 3):

## [SOGL](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL), <s>31</s> <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 25 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/master/chartable.md)

```
∫³2\@*O"²b“2⁵I%*r*;I»«nKp
```

Explanation:

```
∫                          iterate input times, pushing 1-indexed counter
 ³                         get 3 total copies of it on stack
  2\                       1 if divides by 2, else 0
    @*                     get that many spaces
      O                    output in a new line
       "²b“                push 1122
           2⁵I%*           multiply 1122 by 2%(iteration+1)
                r          convert to string
                 *         multiply by iteration
                  ;I»«     get one iteration variable ontop of stack
                      n    increase, floor divide by 2, multiply by 2 (gets the amount of bricks in a line)
                       Kp  split that multiplied string in pieces of that length
```

using [this technique](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/124558/59183)
Example output for 9:

```
00
 22
2244
 2244
224422
 224422
22442244
 22442244
2244224422
```

#### 22 bytes

```
∫³2\@*O"²b“2⁵I%*;I»«mp
```

The command `m` has been documentated on [the 1st SOGL commit](https://github.com/dzaima/SOGL/blob/f271baa60c11a24abec684cb9406f11c287ed315/charDefsParser/data/charDefs.txt#L359), just not implemented.

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>22</s> <s>21</s> <s>20</s> <s>18</s> 17 bytes

Uses the interesting fact that `4^(N+2)/5 = [3,12,51,204,...] = b[11,1100,110011,11001100,...]`

```
F4NÌm5÷bDðì}r·IF,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fzcTvcE@u6eHtSS6HNxxeU1t0aLunm87//4YGAA)

**Explanation**

```
F                     # for N in 0...input-1 do
 4                    # push 4
  NÌ                  # push N+2
    m                 # push 4^(N+2)
     5÷               # integer division by 5
       b              # convert to binary
        D             # duplicate
         ðì           # prepend a space to the copy
           }          # end loop
            r         # reverse stack
             ·        # multiply top of stack by 2
              IF      # input times do
                ,     # print with newline
```

Comment: Sorry, I improved my answer - nice method though!

Comment: @JonathanAllan: Of course you did ;) Thanks! Pretty cool idea of handling the indentation with mod2 rotations in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

### PHP, <s>61</s> 59

```
aa<?for(;++$i<$argn;)echo"
",str_pad(" "[~$i&1],2+$i,bbcc);
```

works pretty much like the python versions but uses all three colors if possible. No trailing new line.

```
-2 bytes by @user63956. Thanks !
```

Comment: You can save two bytes with `aa<?for...`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 29 bytes

```
VQI!%hN2pd)Vh/N2p*2@G%+NH3)pb
```

[Test it online!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=VQI%21%25hN2pd%29Vh%2FN2p%2A2%40G%25%2BNH3%29pb&input=7&debug=0)

**Explanations**

```
VQI!%hN2pd)Vh/N2p*2@G%+NH3)pb

VQ                               For N in range(0, input)
  I!%hN2pd)                      If N is odd, print a leading space
           Vh/N2          )      For H in range(0, N / 2 + 1)
                   @G%+NH3       Select the letter at position (N + H) % 3 in the alphabet
                 *2              Then make it a two letters string ("aa" or "bb" or "cc")
                p                Print it
                           pb    End the line by printing a new line
```

I am sure there are a lot of ways to shorten that code, but I am king of tired right now... Will try later.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 125 bytes

```
@set s=█
@for /l %%i in (2,1,%1)do @call:c
:c
@set s= %s:█= %
@set s=%s:▓=█%
@set s=%s:░=▓%
@set s=%s:  =░░%
@echo %s%
```

Note: Save this in CP437 or CP850 or some such. Works by rotating the colours each time. Since I can't map over the string to perform the rotation, I use four replacements, using spaces as a temporary stage. This then also allows me to prefix a space every line, so that two spaces turn into a new block. Sample output:

```
░░
 ▓▓
░░██
 ▓▓░░
░░██▓▓
```